# How To - Button to change a dropdown value?

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I would like to ask how can I make a button change a value of a field.

[image: 1]
As seen on the image above, The Dropdown Status should be changed from 'Not Paid' to 'Paid.' and the people told me from the sugar community is to alter the metadata. I tried, but I have trouble calling the field and changing its value.
All I know is, my 'Status' field is LBL_Quote_Stage.

Any possible solutions please?
Also, here's my metadata code for the Module 'UA_Quotes'

```
<?php  
$module_name = 'UA_Quotes';  
$viewdefs [$module_name] =   
array (  
  'DetailView' =>   
  array (  
    'templateMeta' =>   
     array (  
       'form' =>   
            array (  
                 'closeFormBeforeCustomButtons' => true,  
                 'buttons' =>   
                     array (  
                        0 => 'EDIT',  
                        1 => 'DELETE',  
                        2 =>   
                           array (  
            'customCode' => '<input id="MonthlyQuote" title="Monthly Quote" class="button" type="button"   
                    name="Quote Payment" value="Quote Payment" onclick="alert(\'How to change status :(\')">',  
      ),  
    ),  
    'footerTpl' => 'modules/UA_Quotes/tpls/DetailViewFooter.tpl',  
  ),  
  'maxColumns' => '2',  
  'widths' =>   
  array (  
    0 =>   
    array (  
      'label' => '10',  
      'field' => '30',  
    ),  
    1 =>   
    array (  
      'label' => '10',  
      'field' => '30',  
    ),  
  ),  
  'useTabs' => false,  
  'tabDefs' =>   
  array (  
    'LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL2' =>   
    array (  
      'newTab' => false,  
      'panelDefault' => 'expanded',  
    ),  
  ),  
),  
'panels' =>   
array (  
  'lbl_editview_panel2' =>   
  array (  
    0 =>   
    array (  
      0 => 'name',  
      1 =>   
      array (  
        'name' => 'ua_contracts_ua_quotes_1_name',  
      ),  
    ),  
    1 =>   
    array (  
      0 =>   
      array (  
        'name' => 'monthlystart_c',  
        'label' => 'LBL_MONTHLYSTART',  
      ),  
      1 =>   
      array (  
        'name' => 'quote_stage',  
        'studio' => 'visible',  
        'label' => 'LBL_QUOTE_STAGE',  
      ),  
    ),  
    2 =>   
    array (  
      0 =>   
      array (  
        'name' => 'monthlydeadline_c',  
        'label' => 'LBL_MONTHLYDEADLINE',  
      ),  
    ),  
  ),  
),  
  ),  
);  
?>
```

I'm using sugarCE 6.5, Thanks guys! :(

Comment: Is alert working once you clicked on Quote payment button?

Comment: Yes, the alert is working. :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to make ajax call on click of Quote Payment button.

1. create a new javascript file and include it in your module through metadata **OR** Write a js functiona directly in view.detail.php file **OR** Call a function which you are going to call in 'customCode'=> onclick event
2. Your js code will be look like

> ```
> var record = $("#record").val();  // value of record which you can see in
> var fdata = { 'record':record };
> $.ajax({
>     url: "ajaxFiles/addPayment.php?&fdata="+fdata+"",
>     type: 'POST',
>     data: fdata,
>     dataType: 'html',
>     async: false,
>     error: function(resp){},
>     success: function(resp){
>         //refresh the page
>     }     
> });
> ```

3. Create `addPayment.php` in `root/ajaxFiles/addPayment.php` folder

> ```
> include("../config.php");
> $localhost = $sugar_config['dbconfig']['db_host_name'];
> $user = $sugar_config['dbconfig']['db_user_name'];
> $password = $sugar_config['dbconfig']['db_password'];
> $db_name = $sugar_config['dbconfig']['db_name'];
> $recordId= $_POST['record'];
> //write a query to update the status of the field
> ```

Hope this will solve your issue. Thanks.

Comment: If I were to use the onClick event, I should call a function that calls the ajax that calls the addPayment.php? :( I'm lose right now. apologies. we haven't tackled Ajax in school yet.

Comment: You just need to write one js function and put the ajax call into it. Do some RnD on it. I have given almost 90% solution. Dont expect spoon-feeding.